# Dynamic select option with Ajax, json and PHP keep option selected after submit

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have a simple dynamically generated select option with Ajax from a json file, what I failed to do is to keep the formerly selected option as selected after submitting the form. Tried that with PHP variable sent to JS but I couldn't find a way to use PHP code inside script tag and echo-ing everything with PHP is ugly. Any idea?

My PHP + AJAX code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', -1);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo '</pre>';
}

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="getsrc" method="post">
            <select name="links" id="links"></select>
        </form>
    </body>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        //get a reference to the select element
        $select = $('#links');
        //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
        $.ajax({
            url: 'links.json',
            dataType:'JSON',
            success:function(data){
                //clear the current content of the select
                $select.html('');
                //iterate over the data and append a select option
                $select.append('<option value="">Please select...</option>');
                $.each(data.link, function(key, val){
                    $select.append('<option value="' + val.name + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
                })
            },
            error:function(){
                //if there is an error append a 'none available' option
                $select.html('<option id="-1">none available</option>');
            }
        });

        $("#links").change(function(){
            this.form.submit();
        });

    </script>
</html>
```

My JSON file:

```
{"link": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "link1.html"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "link2.html"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "link3.html"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "link4.html"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "link5.html"
  }
]}
```

Comment: If you use AJAX to get the JSON data (an extra round trip to the server, instead of parse the JSON with PHP and render full form), why don't you use AJAX for the submit as well ? In this case there will be NO page (re)load and your select will stay with selected value ...

Comment: These were the requirements for my homework, otherwise I would have used only PHP for this :)

Comment: I am preparing an answer with multiple options ;)

Comment: Can't wait! Multiple options are best. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Use AJAX for the submit as well, in this way there will be NO page (re)load and the select will keep the previous value as desired.

```
$("#links").change(function(){
    var $f = $(this).parent('form');

    $.post(
        'yourServerScript.php',
        $f.serialize(), //+ "&a=you-can-attach-extra-params-if-you-like",
        function(data, tStatus, xhr){
            // do whatever the server response is ...

            if (data.success) {
                // do whatever you want if you pass success from the server (in result JSON)
            } else {
                // here you've stated an error, deal with it ...
            }
        },
        'json'
    )
})
```

Your response from the server 'yourServerScript.php' which consumes your post data, should return something like:

`{"success":true or false, ... other data that you want to send after processing the form post ...}`

**Option 2:**

You can still send the post normally and the page will (re)load from the server the process result of the form data, and in this case, to keep selected the value(s) previously selected you have again multiple options, but I will present to you only an elegant one:

From your PHP script, which seems to be the same for processing the post and the page render, you can add a data attribute on the `<select>` which specifies the default selected value(s)

```
<form id="getsrc" method="post">
    <select name="links" id="links"<?php if(!empty($_POST['links'])) echo 'data-selected="' . $_POST['links'] . '"'; ?>></select>
</form>
```

Then, in your AJAX script which loads the JSON and populates the select with options, you check for this data-selected attribute

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'links.json',
    dataType:'JSON',
    success:function(data){
        //clear the current content of the select
        $select.html('');
        //iterate over the data and append a select option
        $select.append('<option value="">Please select...</option>');
        $.each(data.link, function(key, val){
            $select.append('<option value="' + val.name + '"' + (val.name == $select.data('selected') ? ' selected' : '') + '>' + val.name + '</option>');
        })
    },
    error:function(){
        //if there is an error append a 'none available' option
        $select.html('<option id="-1">none available</option>');
    }
});
```

PS: I see that you put the `name` from the JSON to the `<option>` value, there should be the ID, and then check the ID against the data-selected value (the one sent to the server using POST)

Comment: The only problem with `Option 2` is I get a parsing error, unexpected token if. Did you mean Ajax code or PHP?

Comment: can you be more specific ? Option two is only PHP / HTML / JavaScript and changes a little bit your AJAX response callback (adds a check for the previously selected value)

Comment: Parse error on line `$select.append('<option value="' + val.name + '"' + (if(val.name == $select.data('selected')) ? ' selected' : '') + '>' + val.name + '</option>');`

Comment: Yeah, stupid me, sorry: $select.append('<option value="' + val.name + '"' + (val.name == $select.data('selected') ? ' selected' : '') + '>' + val.name + '</option>');

Comment: Ok now but I need to select the `data-selected` returned by PHP in the `form` not in `select`, `$select.data('selected')` is undefined never having place.

Comment: Changed to `$("#links").data('selected')` and PHP `data-selected` added to `<select name="links" id="links"></select>` and now works.

Comment: ok, glad to hear. I haven't tested anything, just typed it in here as text, but you've got the principle ;)